# Why Notes and attachment related list showing Edit and Delete button Even If I have read only access for this object?

Tags: salesforce

I have one profile in My organisation  and I am having read only access for  Object in this profile.But In this object Notes and Attachment list is showing Edit and Delete button under action column.Does anyone know of creative work-around?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following explenation for this:

> To delete a note or attachment, you must be the owner of the note or attachment or an administrator with the “Modify all Data” permission. Note ownership is determined by the owner field. Attachment ownership is determined by the created by field.
>   Record owners (except Portal users) can delete attachments on records.
>   Notes and attachments marked as private via the Private checkbox are accessible only to the person who attached them and administrators. For administrators to view private notes and attachments, they need the “View All Data” permission; to edit or delete them, they need the “Modify All Data” permission.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response.But I don't want to delete note or attachment.I am asking why it is showing Delete and Edit button even if i have read only access?